# minus all Object keys by one

Tags: javascript, object

I have object like this:

`let obj = {'0': {x:25, y:12}, '1': {x:55, y:6}, '2': {x:44, y:78} ,...}`

Now when I delete one of the inside objects(key) `delete obj[i];` (based on their x,y) if the deleted inside object be lets say '0', the new object don't have a '0' inside object anymore and it starts from '1' (`{'1': {x:55, y:6}, '2': {x:44, y:78} ,...}`). and that cause some problems later on.

So How can I fix that? like when the '0' gets deleted minus all keys (**after the key that just deleted**) by one.

Comment: It sounds like you want an array, not an object.

Comment: there are particular reasons why You are not using an array in that case?, the solution would be much faster

Comment: @fedeghe  I have too much code build based on this object, at this point I really really don't wanna change all those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments suggest, you seem to want this object to behave like an array, which suggests you should just use an array:

```
[{x:25, y:12}, {x:55, y:6}, {x:44, y:78}]
```

However, if you **must** use this, you can quickly take the values as an array, `splice()` the element out, and spread back to an array. You need to be a little careful because objects don't guarantee order of their elements (another reason to use an array in the first place).

```js
let obj = {'0': {x:25, y:12}, '1': {x:55, y:6}, '2': {x:44, y:78} }

let arr = Object.keys(obj).sort().map(k => obj[k]) // this will preserve order
arr.splice(1, 1)
obj = {...arr}

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the object you want and then move the data to new object,

```js
    let obj = {'0': {x:25, y:12}, '1': {x:55, y:6}, '2': {x:44, y:78} }

    console.log("Before Delete");
    console.log(obj)
var deleteIndex =1;
    delete obj[deleteIndex];
    var obj2={};
    for (var k in obj){
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
           if(k > deleteIndex){
            obj2[k-1] =obj[k];
        }else{
            obj2[k] =obj[k];
        }
      }
    }
    obj=obj2;
        
    console.log("After Delete");
    console.log(obj);
```

Comment: This only works when deleting the first element. When you try to delete index 1 instead of zero, you get an object with indexes `1` and `-1`, that's probably wrong.

Comment: @MarkMeyer : updated code to support the random location delete

Answer (score 0):

`obj[i]` has gone becase you have deleted it !  If you want to set it to some other value the use...`obj[i] = { x: 0, y: 0 }` this creates a new object in place of the old one.

Or use an Array...

`let obj =  [ {x:25, y:12}, {x:55, y:6},{x:44, y:78} ,... ]`

then

`obj.splice(0,1)`

and you have...

`[ {x:55, y:6},{x:44, y:78} ,.. ]`

with...

`obj[0] is {x:55, y:6}`

Answer (score 0):

what about a function to delete the element?

```
let obj1 = {'0': {x:25, y:12}, '1': {x:55, y:6}, '2': {x:44, y:78}};
function del(o, index) {
    let ret = {}, j = 0;
    for (let i in o){
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(i) && ~~i != ~~index){
            ret[j++] = o[i]
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
let obj2 = del(obj1, 1);
```